# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE android

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, httpclient

trying to upload large video using below code but getting this error<`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE`>. i guess its happening due to multiple classpath but how to rectify in eclipse. and for this i have used jar files from `http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi`.have included only httpclient-4.4.jar, httpcore-4.4.jar, httpmime-4.4.jar from the link.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    int SELECT_VIDEO = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select a Video "), SELECT_VIDEO);       
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
                System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO");
                Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                String selectedPath = getPath(selectedVideoUri);
                System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO Path : " + selectedPath);
                try {
                    uploadVideo(selectedPath);
                } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }      
        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
        int fileSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
        long duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)));
         return filePath;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) throws ParseException, IOException {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL");

        FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
        StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + videoPath);
        StringBody description = new StringBody("This is a description of the video");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
        reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
        reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
        if (resEntity != null) {
          System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
        } // end if

        if (resEntity != null) {
          resEntity.consumeContent( );
        } // end if

        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
    } // end of uploadVideo( )

}
```

Logcat:

```
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632): Process: com.example.testingandroid, PID: 20632
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.toString(ContentType.java:153)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.<init>(MultipartFormEntity.java:52)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:226)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.getEntity(MultipartEntity.java:119)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.getContentType(MultipartEntity.java:150)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.isMoMMS(AbstractHttpClient.java:757)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:581)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at com.example.testingandroid.MainActivity.uploadVideo(MainActivity.java:162)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at com.example.testingandroid.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:113)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3549)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3596)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
02-16 14:16:18.421: E/AndroidRuntime(20632):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: asked already multiple times ... android framework already has (older) version of apache httpclient ... you cannot use those libraries as is ... you have to repackage em

Comment: i did check but couldnt find relavent solution so can u please be more clear?

Comment: how to repackage them? u mean rename the files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366430/getting-nosuchfielderror-instance-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueparser this solution is given for android studio and most of the solution are given for android studio only.

Comment: FSM save us!... do some research ... all you need is to find the jar ... http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chttpclient-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366430/getting-nosuchfielderror-instance-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueparser

Comment: can anyone provide a solution for eclipse project?

Comment: Helloe @Anitha  you find this solutions ? i have same problem

Comment: hi @JosephMekwan this error occur due to wrong httpclient-4.4.jar, httpcore-4.4.jar, httpmime-4.4.jar so please use proper jar files then this issue will be fixed

Comment: hii  @Anitha i set all my libs configuration as i ask question in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711754/android-eclipse-error-on-file-upload-to-server , if you find any problems then please tell me , i solve this from last many days, but not fixes..

Answer (score 8):

Your code could get rid off the deprecated code of `MultipartEntity`and use `MultipartEntityBuilder`. However the specific problem related here is that the core Android libraries conflict with the newly added ones. Also now there are maven repositories available. You could include the following code into the below file:

> build.grade (Module:app)

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

It is pretty much simple to work the way around. Thanks to [oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366430/getting-nosuchfielderror-instance-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueparser)