# Android eclipse error on File upload to server

Tags: android, apache, http, multipartform-data, multipartentity

In my android eclipse project, i want to upload image file with name and email fields to server.

But i got the following error : my logcat is following :

```
NoSuchFieldError - BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE

E/AndroidRuntime(25348): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
```

my entire logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25348): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(25348): Process: com.example.uploadfiles, PID: 25348
E/AndroidRuntime(25348): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while    executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348): Caused by:  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:  org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.toString(ContentType.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.<init>(MultipartFormEntity.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.build(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at com.example.uploadfiles.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at com.example.uploadfiles.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(25348):    ... 4 more
```

My code for uploading image and some fields are following :

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {

            File image = new File(iPath);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(image);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constant.signUp);

            post.setHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            multipartEntity.addPart("ID", new StringBody("1"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("pID", new StringBody("1"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("userPhoto", fileBody);
            multipartEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("joseph@gmail.com"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("cell", new StringBody("1234567890"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("username", new StringBody("joseph"));

            post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
            // post.setEntity((MultipartEntityBuilder) multipartEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, localContext);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),
                    "UTF-8"));

            HttpResponse responses = client.execute(post);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.v("multiPartPost HTTP Response", responseBody);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("error=" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {

            if (sResponse != null) {
                JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                int success = JResponse.getInt("SUCCESS");
                String message = JResponse.getString("MESSAGE");
                if (success == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    caption.setText("");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "excepttion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

My libs folder have following necessary libraries :

[image]

And in my java build path :

[image]
and in order-export in properties
[image]

Now i what have to do to solve this error : i working entire day for solving this but not, so please any one suggest me to how to solve this error, it very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is main problem of libs., that all might faced, wrong library causes this issue,

So, following step helpful to you :

(1) Code : Following code is successfully upload  photo to the server :

```
     btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Constant.bitmapPicture != null) {
                StoreByteImage(Constant.bitmapPicture, 90, "my_image");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

StoreByteImage(...) :

```
   public boolean StoreByteImage(Bitmap bitmap, int quality, String expName) {

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/Example");
    if (myNewFolder.mkdirs()) {
        myNewFolder.mkdir();
    }
    try {


        iPath = myNewFolder + "/" + expName + ".jpg";
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myNewFolder + "/" + expName + ".jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

        new ImageUploadTask().execute();

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Class ImageUploadTask

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String sResponse;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {
            //

            File image = new File(iPath);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(image);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(YourImageUploadURLHere);

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Constant.bitmapPicture.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            entity.addPart("ID", new StringBody("1"));
            entity.addPart("pID", new StringBody("1"));
            entity.addPart("userPhoto", fileBody);
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("email@gmail.com"));
            entity.addPart("cell", new StringBody("1234567890"));
            entity.addPart("username", new StringBody("name"));

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),
                    "UTF-8"));

            sResponse = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("responce=" + sResponse);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("error=" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponses) {
        try {

            if (sResponses != null) {

                JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject(sResponse.toString());

                if (jsonObjSend.getString("status").equals("success")) {

                    // another code
                } else if (jsonObjSend.getString("status").equals("fail")) {

                    // another code
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "excepttion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

(2) First Remove All libs/jar file from the your libs Folder :

(3) Find Following libraries/jar file from the internet and put in libs folder :

[image]

(4) Add jar from the libraries tab :

[image]

(5) Your Order and Export libraries/jar file Tick mark same as following :

[image]

Ok, Done. Just these simple steps helpful to you upload image file to server.
hope these helphul to you and others.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded from 4.3 to 4.4 before i have noticed this error. 
Could be 4.3 causing it.

Comment: so how could you notice this error at all if you upgraded before you noticed it. Or if you upgraded but you see the error how it can be 4.3 issue. Fix your answer please.