# How can I use Multipart in Android?

Tags: android, upload, multipart

I want to upload multiple image at once.
so I found 'MultipartEntityBuilder' but It is not working well.

It's my source...

```
public void executeMultipartPost() throws Exception {
    try {

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


        builder.addTextBody("file1", byteArray.toString());
        builder.addTextBody("file2", byteArray2.toString());

        // send
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_URL);
        httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        // response
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();

        // result
        String result = stringBuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When Debugging, 'httpPost.setEntity(builder.build())' this line is error.

and there is no 'Caused by~' ,but Process: NoSuchFiledError in logcat...

but I think I made image to bitmap then send it to FTP. what is wrong..? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code could get rid off the deprecated code of MultipartEntityand use MultipartEntityBuilder. However the specific problem related here is that the core Android libraries conflict with the newly added ones. Also now there are maven repositories available. You could try the following code into the below file:

```
build.grade (Module:app)
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

[Getting NoSuchFieldError INSTANCE org/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366430/getting-nosuchfielderror-instance-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueparser)

Comment: hm... you mean the version is quite different?? I will change to 4.3.6. but I'm using eclipse-android... so I need jar. I will try!! Thanks.

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711754/android-eclipse-error-on-file-upload-to-server

Comment: Omg... Thanks men!!

Comment: I'm sure It's my glad. As many ppl said, u saved my time. haha Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

public static UploadResult upload(final Bitmap bitmap, final Context context) {

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    UploadResult result = null;
    try {
        URL uri = new URL(context.getString(R.string.base_url) + context.getString(R.string.api_upload));
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        con.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("connection", "keep-alive");
        String BOUNDARY = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String LINE_END = "\r\n";
        String PREFIX = "--";
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        String sb = PREFIX +
                BOUNDARY +
                LINE_END +
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"tmp.png\"" + LINE_END +
                "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8" + LINE_END +
                LINE_END;

        os.write(sb.getBytes());
        os.write(Util.Bitmap2Byte(bitmap));

        os.write(LINE_END.getBytes());
        byte[] end_data = (PREFIX + BOUNDARY + PREFIX + LINE_END).getBytes();
        os.write(end_data);

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        int code = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("code:" + code);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));

        if (code == 200) {
            String ch;
            while (null != (ch = br.readLine())) {
                builder.append(ch);
            }
        }
        con.disconnect();

        String response = builder.toString();
        if (!response.isEmpty()) {
            result = JSON.parseObject(response, UploadResult.class);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: it is the http response, you can change it to String, if response is json or xml, the UploadResult is response entity

Comment: JSON is fastjson, you can also change it to gson

Comment: got it. Thanks! I will also try!! Thank you! :)

Comment: hm... me yi! Can I ask one more thing?? I want to upload multiple!! but this code is only one bitmap. but I want send more than 10 bitmap at once.... T_T

Comment: Do I just put more 'os.write(Util.Bitmap2Byte(bitmap));' ??

Comment: if you have more bitmap, you need to circulation String sb = PREFIX +
                BOUNDARY +
                LINE_END +
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"tmp.png\"" + LINE_END +
                "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8" + LINE_END +
                LINE_END;

        os.write(sb.getBytes());
        os.write(Util.Bitmap2Byte(bitmap));

        os.write(LINE_END.getBytes());
        byte[] end_data = (PREFIX + BOUNDARY + PREFIX + LINE_END).getBytes();
        os.write(end_data);

Comment: if you have more file

Comment: That is greate idea! Thanks! loop is start from String sb to os.write(end_data)? and Does it means os.write many times? then one connection?? 
When I tired, getresponsecode is tooo long time.. as one by one. Can I ask you the reason?? I guess one connection multi sending is more quick than one connection sending one by one. but It is not...

Comment: this is only one connection

Comment: exactly. so Nice idea. but when I call outputstream.write() manytimes (when I use loop for multiple) it makes error. so I guess... is there max_size of outputstream..?? I'm thinking really thanks to your reply..!!

Comment: if HttpURLConnection is not disconnect, this is only one connection, if you want to send more, you only need to loop String sb to os.write(end_data);

Comment: oh, may be, the may be have the max_size, may be 64k or more

Comment: ah...!!!! so when I try call many times...(sometimes I need more 10 loop), Is it necessary to face error!?

Comment: you should change the filename, one bitmap one filename

Comment: yep! I always change filename in loop. and error stream is...

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ks_c_5601-1987"/><title>500 - ���� ���� ���.</title><style type="text/css"><!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-...

Comment: getting from server is broken the String... I don't know ... frankly First error is  <!DOCTYPE html><html>    <head>        <title>runtime-error</title>        <meta name="viewport"  ... 
so I added web.config  "<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="default.htm" />"

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ks_c_5601-1987"/><title>500 - ���� ���� ���.</title><style type="text/css"><!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0

Comment: 0 0;color:#000000;} #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#555555;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}--></style></head><body><div id="header"><h1>���� ���</h1></div><div id="content"> <div class="content-container"><fieldset>  <h2>500 - ���� ���� ���.</h2>  <h3>ã�� �ִ� ���ҽ��� ����� �־� ǥ���� �� ���ϴ�.</h3> </fieldset></div></div></body></html>

Comment: these 2 log is whole message getting from error stream.

Comment: this string is broken, i see is ���� ���� ���

Comment: Omg... damn!! I got it... may be, may be(as u said. lol) outputstream has a max_size. so I changed like this :: ByteArrayInputStream bs =null;           int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;byte[] temp =bitmapToByteArray(bitmap.get(i)); bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(temp);bytesAvailable = bs.available(); int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize); os.write(temp, 0, bufferSize);  ::

It is uploaded completely...!!!

Comment: hm... not 100%.... I try other page.... It is still error..... but I don't know what is common and different...!!!! T_T