# NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE

Tags: android, http, post

i got the above Problem. (java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE)

I found this solution: [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538078/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueformatter-in/29207914#29207914)

But i dont know where to use the code snippet... where i can found the file (build.grade (Module:app) ).

Comment: If you are working in Android Studio, It should be in Gradle Scripts section

Comment: I working on Eclipse

Comment: For Eclipse you need to Download the latest jar for Android from http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient-android/source/httpcomponents-client-android-4.3.5-src.zip andadd it to reference lib

Comment: I did this allready, but the i cant this error:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE