# Error on Http.Post.setEntity with MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, post, request, httpentity

I was trying to connect my Android application to my Flask Server on localhost when i had this problem. To do more easy to detect the error i will let you the code of my Android application and the output of the log of Android Studio.

First, the code of my Android application: It only try to upload an image to a server when you touch the screen of your device. The code not is finished yet because i detect the error before i end it.

```
public class Imagen extends ActionBarActivity {
private int SELECT_IMAGE = 237;
private int TAKE_PICTURE = 829;
private int n_touchs=0;
private EditText lblPhoto;
private ImageView imgPhoto;
private RelativeLayout world;
private HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
private HttpPost post=new HttpPost("192.168.1.138");
private MultipartEntityBuilder builder=MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagen);
    lblPhoto=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblPhoto);
    imgPhoto=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
    world=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.world);
    world.setOnTouchListener(new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (n_touchs == 0) {
                dialogPhoto();
                n_touchs++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void dialogPhoto(){
    try{
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Seleccionar de la galería", "Hacer una foto"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Seleccionar una foto");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                switch(item){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_IMAGE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), TAKE_PICTURE);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } catch(Exception e){}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_imagen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try{
        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                lblPhoto.setText("ok");
                imgPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                File file_image=new File(selectedImage.toString());
                FileBody file_send=new FileBody(file_image);
                builder.addPart("file",file_send);
                HttpEntity entity=builder.build();
                post.setEntity(entity);
            }
        }
        if(requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                lblPhoto.setText("ok");
                imgPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                File file_image=new File(selectedImage.toString());
                FileBody file_send=new FileBody(file_image);
                builder.addPart("file",file_send);
                post.setEntity(builder.build());
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

}

And my log output is this:

```
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.toString(ContentType.java:153)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.<init>(MultipartFormEntity.java:52)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:226)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.build(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:230)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at com.example.bryan.imagen.Imagen.onActivityResult(Imagen.java:122)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3514)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3561)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:168)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-05 20:01:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(11109):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope you can help me with this error and ssorry for my English. Thanks.

Comment: `It only try to upload an image to a server when you touch the screen of your device. `. No. When the user touches the screen the user is asked if he wants to take a picture with the camera or pick one from the gallery.

Comment: You should really read some more posts about picking a file from the galler and uploding it. Your code is a mess now. If you read 25 stackoverflow pages with tag android you will find clean code. You can also google for it.

Comment: Yeah, i know that the user is asked when he touchs the screen but after that in the methon onActivityResult i try to do this:

File file_image=new File(selectedImage.toString());
                FileBody file_send=new FileBody(file_image);
                builder.addPart("file",file_send);
                HttpEntity entity=builder.build();
                post.setEntity(entity);
And i think the error is there. And sorry for my code but i am beginner with Android.

Comment: You did not have to repeat that as i had seen that already of course. Imagen.java line 122 is mentioned in the logcat. Which code is on that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading post in stack overflow when i saw this post : [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538078/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueformatter-in)

There is the solution to my problem.