# MultipartEntityBuilder to send pictures to rail server

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, apache, mime

I am trying to send a `MultipartEntityBuilder`  to my Rails server. However when i try to build it it crashes and gives me the error

> 03-25 09:44:50.001 W/System.err﹕
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> No static method
> create(Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
> in class Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType; or its super classes
> (declaration of 'org.apache.http.entity.ContentType

```
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntityBuilder entity = new MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        for(int index=0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) { 
            ContentBody cb;
            if(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("File")) { 
                File file = new File(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue());
                FileBody isb = new FileBody(file);
                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), isb);
            } else { 
                // Normal string data 
                                    
                cb =  new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue(),ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),cb); 
            } 
        } 
 return entity.build();
```

This is the code i am using and i am still getting errors on the building of the the MultipartEntity it'll say the error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using httpmime version 4.3.6

I tried using 4.4+ but always the same problem.

Comment: In android studio, using the File | Project Structure | Dependency | + button, do not use the Library Dependecy which is using Maven which is adding latest httmime. Instead donwload 4.3.6 as @Matheus has mentioned and add it as File Dependency. Your build.gradle then will lhave a line like compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar'
Remember you may need to Sync your project with Gradle files in Android Studio again

Comment: Or just put `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'` inside `dependencies` on your `build.gradle` file