# Volley upload file/image without using httpcilent

Tags: android, android-volley

as MultipartEntity is removed from sdk 23 what is best way to upload images with other string params to server . 
 i did refer [How to upload file using Volley library in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262829/how-to-upload-file-using-volley-library-in-android) but here only file are present

how i can upload image using volley

Comment: What is your issue? Your question, implementation is unclear

Comment: You can read my github sample https://github.com/ngocchung/volleynoapache

Answer (score 0):

Use this below link. You can know  more about volley

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Retrofit is another rest client to know more about retrofit see the below link

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: i don't want to use retrofit as of now ,and that volley link not provides image sending

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley Use this link to upload image.Before asking question..Google it

Comment: my friend read title i don't want httpcilent which removed from sdks 23, given link use that