# Android Volley ECONNRESET

Tags: android, exception, android-volley, econnreset

I try to use `Volley` library and upload image to server. This library should do this process in standalone mode, but have got following error message:

> java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset
>   by peer)

Is it maybe a server side misconfiguration?
I try to upload a `jpeg` image with this code:

```
private void uploadImage(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    loading.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android

Comment: I have already checked this question, but I think it is a different problem.

Comment: Please include the code where you are sending the request so that we can examine it and suggest solutions.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla : Code snippet added.

Comment: OK, a quick question, does the server accept uploads? That is, did you test this using a Web browser or some other client and did it work?

Comment: I have transfer files only with WinSCP. Should I test with another script maybe? What is the necessary configuration in this way?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla : I have just tested it with a simple PHP image uploader script and that is working, can upload files to folder.

Comment: OK, instead of using `StringRequest`, you should try and use a MultiPart Request and specify your image as a FilePart. You can look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley) - shout if you need help in adapting this to your situation.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla : Thanks, but it is really interesting, because I have tried same code with several images and it can upload some without any error and save as `png` to server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111610/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-kovacs-akos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to be sure, you need to change your `uploadImage()` into something like this:

```
private void uploadImage(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    //here you use your custom multi-part-request as I suggested in the comment:
    ImageUploadRequest imageUploadReq = new ImageUploadRequest(UPLOAD_URL,            
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    loading.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, yourImageFile);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(imageUploadReq);
}
```

Where your `ImageUploadRequest` class is defined as demonstrated in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley) like this:

```
public class ImageUploadRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";

private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
private final Response.Listener<T> mListener;
private final File mImageToUpload;
protected Map<String, String> headers;

public ImageUploadRequest(String uploadURL, ErrorListener errorListener, Listener<T> listener, File imageFileToUpload){
    super(Method.POST, uploadURL, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mImageToUpload = imageFileToUpload;
    //call the helper method to build the multipart entity
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

    if (headers == null || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

    return headers;
}

private void buildMultipartEntity(){
    mBuilder.addBinaryBody(FILE_PART_NAME, mImageToUpload, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), mImageToUpload.getName());
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType(){
    String contentTypeHeader = mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
    return contentTypeHeader;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream bos, building the multipart request.");
    }

    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    T result = null;
    return Response.success(result, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

I have made some minor adaptations of [Upload an image using Google Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley) to your specific situation. I hope this helps you and that others may also find it useful.

Comment: There are several errors, when try to resolve `ContentType`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get this error when I don't use url encoded queries.

Take a look [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)