# "Volley" Error: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: sockets, request, timeout, android-volley, econnreset

This is not a duplicate question, because I did not find anything about this error with "volley".

My problem happens when the connection is very slow, one of my services returns this error:

```
         VolleyError={NoConnectionError@5719}"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
         VolleyError.networkResponse.data=java.lang.NullPointerException
         VolleyError.networkResponse.statusCode=java.lang.NullPointerException
         VolleyError.networkResponse=null
```

I have searched a lot, and find this

```
         System.setProperty("http.keepAlive","false");
```

but I don't know if that right.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : [android-volley-econnres‌​et](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155789/android-volley-econnres%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bet)

Too , in my case problem was from server side and proxy that after enable VPN proxy , problem resolved.

[image]

checkout server side