# Android upload image from ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have PHP code that receives an image from POST:

```
$_FILES['file']['name'] and $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].
```

On Android, I need to get the image that is shown in an ImageView and send that to the PHP script on the server. For iOS I created code to do it using POST request and multipart/form-data. But on Android I did not find a way to do this.

Comment: Yes , its possible . You can start with search on google , stackoverflow or blog sites. And come here with a little piece of code. We always here but you must effort something.You can search for Volley , Retrofit , HttpUrlConnection, OkHttp. Have a good day.

Comment: I think so you would refer to this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is a very useful library to implement Android HTTP clients. I think it can be useful for you.