# Upload an image to server in Android without encoding to Base64 using Volley

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, encryption

I have an uploader in android which uploads an image file(which is encrypted by an algorithim to 400bytes) but the file has to be decoded to base64 string to be saved to a mysql db as a string and upload the image to a folder.

The problem is that after decoding the file to `base64` string it looses its byte encrypted algorithm format.(The image size reduces from 400 bytes to less)

This is what i have done:

```
Bitmap b = this.toGrayscale(mRegisterImage);  //this image file is 400byte encrypted
uploadImage(b);
```

This is the function `uploadimage`

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {  //This is what converts the image to 64encoded format string
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);  //Thos is what compresses image hence loosing bytes
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(final Bitmap bmp) {
    // Showing the progress dialog
    try {
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Uploading fingerprint...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, Config.url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        // Disimissing the progress dialog
                            debugMessage("Return Message: " + s);
                            loading.dismiss();
                                                }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        try { // Dismissing the progress dialog
                            loading.dismiss();
                            // Showing toast
                            debugMessage(volleyError.getMessage());
                        } catch (Exception r) {
                            debugMessage("onerrorresponse: "+volleyError.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                    throws AuthFailureError {
                // Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bmp);

                // Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                // Adding parameters
                params.put("image", image);

                return params;
            }
        };
        // Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        // Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (Exception r) {
        debugMessage("out: "+r.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is the PHP CODE:

```
  $sql ="SELECT id FROM fingerprint ORDER BY id ASC";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $id = 0;

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      $id = $row['id'];
  }

 $path = "$id.png";

 $actualpath = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/PhotoUploadWithText/$path";

 $sql = "INSERT INTO fingerprint (value) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

     file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));

     echo "Successfully Uploaded";
   }
```

Everything works quite fine but is there a way that i can upload the actual image without converting it to a string in android using volley library. The above code compresses the image to the string, How do i change this compression so that the bytes arent lost

Comment: nitpick: base64 isn't encryption. it's an ENCODING.

Comment: Okay but the file is size and original output is changed

Comment: plus your database code is basically totally broken. You do **NOT** get an id by pulling all the existing ids and throwing away all but the last one. plus, the $id you DO end up with will NOT be the id of the new record you created when you insert that url, so you're killing the id/url association by making everythin be off-by-one.

Comment: The original file has an encryption

Comment: The main issue is not on the database but on sending the file to php in an original format

Comment: base64 is a 1:1 encoding. what you put into it will be what you get out of it. if something's changing the size of your data, then it's not b64's fault.

Comment: is there another way of uploading the files without use of encoding way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload an image using Google Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley)

Comment: No its not, I have updated the question, i would like to upload without compressing the image

Answer (score 0):

Basically no, because `Http` message body can carry `byte data` only so can't send any other form of this large data through `http` protocol.

`Http` transfer data by using `TCP` which use commonly `switching techniques` in this case. Protocols either format data in `bit` or `byte` level  where  `byte` level is mostly used so if you looking for another way then you are out of luck today

So even if you are using `StringRequest` and passing data as string `parameter` eventually your every `parameter` is converted to `byte array` type so you can't escape from converting data to bytes.

Comment: The above transfers it inform of a string, The original file is in form of a byte, How do i transport this byte without converting it to a string format

Comment: letme add little more info to my answer

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong , who ever down-vote this otherwise share your knowledge with us by giving an answer if you can