# No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, android-volley, multipartentity

I get the following error:

```
Process: com.project.publiko, PID: 27061
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.toString(ContentType.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.<init>(MultipartFormEntity.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.getEntity(MultipartEntity.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:180)
    at com.project.publiko.CustomMultipartRequest.getBody(CustomMultipartRequest.java:57)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:236)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

Refer error line (Gradle):

```
android {
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

```java
public class CustomMultipartRequest extends Request < String > {
    private Response.Listener < String > mListener = null;
    private Response.ErrorListener mEListener;

    private long cacheTimeToLive = 0;
    //
    private Map < String,
    String > header;
    MultipartEntity entity;

    @Override
    public Map < String,
    String > getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        // you can add your custom headers here
        HashMap < String, String > headers = new HashMap < > ();

        return headers;
    }

    public CustomMultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener eListener, Response.Listener < String > rListener, MultipartEntity entity) {
        super(Method.POST, url, eListener);
        mListener = rListener;
        mEListener = eListener;
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return entity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try { **
            Error Line ** entity.writeTo(bos);
            String entityContentAsString = new String(bos.toByteArray());
            Log.e("volley", entityContentAsString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("DEBUG::Volley", response.toString());
        System.out.println("VolleyQueue: Response Delivered for " + getTag() +
            " (" + getSequence() + ")");
        mListener.onResponse(response);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected Response < String > parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            // Volley does not handle null properly, so implement null response
            // check
            if (response.data.length == 0) {
                byte[] responseData = "{}".getBytes("UTF8");
                response = new NetworkResponse(response.statusCode,
                    responseData, response.headers, response.notModified);
            }

            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(jsonString,
                parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("VolleyQueue: Encoding Error for " + getTag() +
                " (" + getSequence() + ")");
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    public Cache.Entry parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(NetworkResponse response) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Map < String, String > headers = response.headers;
        long serverDate = 0;
        String serverEtag;
        String headerValue;

        headerValue = headers.get("Date");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        serverEtag = headers.get("ETag");

        final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 15 * 60 * 1000; //Fifteen Minutes
        final long cacheExpired = cacheTimeToLive;
        final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
        final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;

        Cache.Entry entry = new Cache.Entry();
        entry.data = response.data;
        entry.etag = serverEtag;
        entry.softTtl = softExpire;
        entry.ttl = ttl;
        entry.serverDate = serverDate;
        entry.responseHeaders = headers;

        return entry;
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        super.deliverError(error);
    }
}
```

Call to the class:

```java
CustomMultipartRequest req = new CustomMultipartRequest(URL, //url where you want to send the multipart request
    elistener, //instance of onErrorResponse Listener
    rlistener, //instance of onResponse Listener
    entityBuilder);
req.setShouldCache(false);
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
rq.add(req);
```

Can you help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NoSuchFieldError INSTANCE org/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366430/getting-nosuchfielderror-instance-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueparser)

Comment: @shayanpourvatan let me try that;

Comment: to use that libraries i need to remove useLibrary {apache}??..@shayanpourvatan

Comment: yes you need to remove that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan getting the same error by using httpmime library and http core

Answer (score 12):

Is a error of the library version 
try with this versions

```
 implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can someone give him an Oscar?

Comment: great answer ! are the authors of the lib aware of this ?

Comment: That's really helped, from where you find out this? any official form or documentation link about this library error?

Comment: How to inform the developers, as of now May 2021 still same error exists.

Comment: You are a saviour!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```