# how do you get a more detailed error message than "Error: Program type already present: <type>"?

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, unirest

Right, so I want to use Unirest on Android for some quick testing because it's more lightweight than, say, Volley.

(need to run it in `androidTest` because I want to test some android-reliant features)

So ...

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'
```

results in

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
```

Right, whatever. So I do a bit of googling and end up finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398616/3322533) here.

sounds simple enough ...

```
androidTestImplementation'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
androidTestImplementation('com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module:'httpclient'
}
```

which gives me

> Error: Program type already present: org.apache.http.Consts

So given that without the `exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module:'httpclient'`, it gives me a

```
Error: Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.AuthOption
```

I would imagine that I "just" have to keep excluding modules until I've excluded everything that would've resulted in a conflict.

But **how do I find out which modules these are?**

Oh, and no, I cannot simply exclude the entire group

```
androidTestImplementation'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
androidTestImplementation('com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

Because that results in

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/nio/reactor/DefaultConnectingIOReactor;
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:85)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:46)
```

Comment: Sounds like version mismatch, are you sure you can't use Retrofit instead?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am indeed looking into Retrofit, thank you for the suggestion. I'll keep the question up, though, as am still very much interested in getting a more meaningful error message out of something like this.